# Chrome extension capturing audio from various conference softwares

Tags: google-chrome, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I want to create a chrome extension that will capture audios coming from meetings that use Zoom, Go-to-meetings, Uberconference..etc. It will capture audio from those apps and also capture audio from the microphone.

I think I am able to capture audio coming from the desktop and microphone but if users have their headphone on, then I wouldn't be able to capture the audio from the desktop.

Anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the tab capture API.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture